# Relation multiple Models

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

long time i been not working with laravel, im strugling in getting some data.

Im trying to get all the bookmakers from a competition but is not getting:

db:

```
leagues:
-id
-name

league_bookmakers:
- id
- league_id
- bookmaker_id

bookmakers:
- id
- name
```

controller:

```
 $example = \App\League::find(440);

    dd($example->bookmakers());
```

Model League:

```
public function bookmakers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(LeagueBookmaker::class);
    }
```

Comment: Remove the parenthesis like that: `dd($example->bookmakers);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call a relation method on a model (`$example->bookmakers()`), it returns the actual relation, allowing you to add additional constraints.

What you need to be calling is the 'dynamic property', which simply returns the data from the relation as-is:

```
$example->bookmakers // without the ()
```

Comment: just one more question, if i wish to include in this relation, the name of the League of the table leagues?

Comment: If you define the inverse of the relationship, you should be able to to `$bookmaker->league->name`.

Comment: Yes, i understand, but the idea is to start with the leagues, and then calling in the bookmakers.

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you mean in your second question then. You can call `$a_league->bookmakers` to get the bookmakers, then from any of those returned bookmakers, you can call `$a_bookmaker->league->name`. If I'm misunderstanding, please clarify.

Comment: Well, using for example "with('')"

Comment: `with('bookmakers')` will simply eager load the relation, meaning if you call `$a_league->bookmakers` at some point, it won't have to perform another query to get the data. Functionally, the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

What are you getting? Are you getting an empty collection? 
As commented try doing this

`dd($example->bookmakers);`

Also, try doing `dd($example)` first and see if it has the `bookmakers` collection property in it.

Answer (score 0):

When you make relation with league_bookmakers table, you will not get bookmakers data directly. In that case, you can define a belongsToMany Relation like below code -

```
public function bookmakers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Bookmaker::class, 'league_bookmakers','league_id', 'bookmaker_id');
    }
```

It will return bookakers table info directly.